# two python files - one file gives json object and another file takes the output as input

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm new to python and apologies if my way of questioning is wrong.

I have two python files. one file will take as input and another file's output. Problem is, I need to pass input one at a time. So python one file will have a for loop and it generates JSON one by one and it should pass JSON one by one in that for loop only. It means python file two will be running and it takes input from python file one and processes and picks the second incoming JSON output from python file one. This process continues till the python one file ends its loop

**pythonone.py file
**

```
import json, time
from faker import Faker

#Create a Faker object to generate fake data for the Producer
fake=Faker()

def myrandomdata(i,j):
    return fake.random_int(min = 1, max = j)

json_obj_list = []
random_ins_id = str(myrandomdata(20000,10000000))
random_inv_item_id = str(myrandomdata(20000,10000000))
random_inv_org_id = str(myrandomdata(1000,100000))
random_loc_id = str(myrandomdata(20000,100000))
qty = myrandomdata(1,100)
loc_type_id = myrandomdata(0,4)

def main():
    for i in range(5):
        json_obj_list={'ID': random_ins_id,
            'QTY': qty,
            'EXT_REF': random_loc_id,
            'INV_ITEM_ID': random_inv_item_id,
            'ORG_ID': random_inv_org_id,
            'SERIAL_NUMBER': loc_type_id
            }
    json_dump = json.dumps(json_obj_list, indent="\t")
    print(json_dump)
    time.sleep(3)
```

**Pythontwo.py
**

```
def process_my_data:
    res= pythonone.main()
    /*I do some process */
```

Guide me on how can i achieve this

I am stuck to wait one file to process and pick second one and then 3rd one and stops till for loop ends from pythonone.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should bring in `threading` concept

- create a producer method for producing JSON
- create a consumer method for consuming that JSON

`condition variable` allows one or more threads to wait until they are notified by another thread

```
import json,time
from threading import *
from faker import Faker

#Create Faker object to generate fake data for Producer
fake=Faker()

def myrandomdata(i,j):
    return fake.random_int(min = 1, max = j)

li = [ ]
random_ins_id = str(myrandomdata(20000,10000000))
random_inv_item_id = str(myrandomdata(20000,10000000))
random_inv_org_id = str(myrandomdata(1000,100000))
random_loc_id = str(myrandomdata(20000,100000))
qty = myrandomdata(1,100)
loc_type_id = myrandomdata(0,4)

def produce():
    for i in range(3):
        condition_object.acquire()
        json_obj_list={'ID': random_ins_id,
            'QTY': qty,
            'EXT_REF': random_loc_id,
            'INV_ITEM_ID': random_inv_item_id,
            'ORG_ID': random_inv_org_id,
            'SERIAL_NUMBER': loc_type_id
            }
        print("produced json",json_obj_list)
        li.append(json_obj_list)
        condition_object.notify()
        condition_object.wait()
        
def consume():
    for i in range(3):
        condition_object.acquire()
        json = li.pop()
        print("the json for consuming ", json)
        condition_object.notify()
        condition_object.wait()
        
        
condition_object = Condition()
T1 = Thread(target=produce)

T2 = Thread(target=consume)

T1.start()

T2.start()
```

- the produces acquires the object and adds the JSON to a common list and notify the consumer and wait for call back
- while the consumer acquires the object gets the JSON and notify the producer to continue from waiting state  while the consumer being in waiting state .

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` needs to return some data, so the caller can use them, also use better names

- you're overwritting `json_obj_list` at each iteration, you need to collect them in a list
- you're generating the random number once, you need to do it for each iteration
- you're not using `i` in your `myrandomdata`, and you can don't need faker for such random int

```py
from random import randrange

def myrandomdata(i, j):
    return randrange(i, j + 1)

def generate_items():
    json_obj_list = []
    for i in range(5):
        json_obj_list.append({'ID': myrandomdata(20000, 10000000),
                              'QTY': myrandomdata(1, 100),
                              'EXT_REF': myrandomdata(20000, 100000),
                              'INV_ITEM_ID': myrandomdata(20000, 10000000),
                              'ORG_ID': myrandomdata(1000, 100000),
                              'SERIAL_NUMBER': myrandomdata(0, 4)})
    return json_obj_list
```

```py
def process_my_data():
    res = pythonone.generate_items()
    for item in res:
        print(type(item), item)
```

Comment: Thanks @azro, But this code returns 5 json objs in single return. I am looking for, for loop generates first json and returns to python two file... then second json file it passes to pythontwo file.. like wise i need...

Comment: I need only one json object and return it...

Comment: @ditil if you want ONE object, you don't need a for-loop, just make the method return one dict, and call the method multiple times

Comment: can we run both files and check whether any json is being generated in pythonone.py and pythontwo.py picks that newly generated json and do the process?

Comment: @ditil : I don't understand what you mean + you really misses some things, so that's very hard to help you. You don't "call multiple file", you call a main file, that calls funtcion in ther files that's it